# For what creates HandlerThread in android-Camera2Video?

Tags: android, android-camera2

For what creates HandlerThread in android-Camera2Video sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java

534 Line

HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();

We do not use thread after run it.

Answer (score -1):

Create a HandlerThread will add an additional thread for running tasks that shouldn't block the UI. For example, you can preload the Camera in a background task :

```
mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
mBackgroundThread.start();
```

Comment: I mean this:  HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start(); We do not use thread after run it.

Comment: he talks about https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L534 which is useless!!! they have normal variables for it https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L335